# Live Meeting Service API Get Info C#

Tags: c#

I need to create a Windows Application that would collect Livemeeting Data and send it through a mail to the administrator!

I need the following:

1. Get the Active Meetings - current meeting name, info, start time, name, owner, location and URL
2. All the users attending the meeting (total number of Attendees)
3. And if there is any ERROR or Problem I need to get that Error details.

How to get all the above info. I intent to use Live meeting Service API.

Progress:

I have found all the code with some search!

But I am able to get the GetPostingURLRequest ,but when I am sending the Request to get meeting information I keep getting this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PlaceWareConfCenter>
    <Fault>
        <FaultCode>Client.BadSyntax.ParseError</FaultCode>
        <FaultString>Error parsing XML request</FaultString>
        <OptionList>
            <TimeOption value="2015-09-08T08:06:55Z" name="time" />
            <StringOption value="zt3tbcc18d" name="rapid.requestId" />
        </OptionList>
    </Fault>
</PlaceWareConfCenter> ​
```

Request I am sending is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
- <PlaceWareConfCenter authUser="username" authPassword="password">
    - <ListMeetingsRequest listDeleted="False">  
        <StringQuery fieldName="mid" operator="=" value="F67SD" /> 
            - <FieldList>  
                <Name>name</Name>   
              </FieldList>  
      </ListMeetingsRequest> 
   </PlaceWareConfCenter>
```

EDITTED AND ADDED CODE:

Code:

```
public XmlDocument PostXmlMessageRequest(XmlDocument xmldoc, string postingUrl)
{
    // Upon entering, xmldoc = messageRequest
    // Upon exit, xmlReply = messageReply;

    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
    XmlDocument xmlReply = null;

    // Post the <messageRequest> element to the conference center;
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postingUrl);
    myReq.Method = "POST";
    myReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    HttpWebResponse myResp = null;
    try
    {
        // Write the XML message to the request stream and
        // send it to the conference center
        //
        byte[] byteArray = encoder.GetBytes(xmldoc.OuterXml);
        myReq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream reqStream = myReq.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        reqStream.Close();

        // Get the response from the conference center
        myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
        Stream respStream = myResp.GetResponseStream();
        if (myResp.ContentType == "application/xml")
        {
            xmlReply = new XmlDocument();
            xmlReply.Load(respStream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log the error or implement other error handling routines
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}\nStack trace: {1}",
                            e.Message, e.StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myResp != null)
            myResp.Close();
    }

    return xmlReply;
}
```

I am following the [MSDN articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963695(v=office.12).aspx) and [MSDN Listing Meetings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb894308%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) below:

Just keep getting the Parse error. I have tried several Messages and checked the XML. Cannot see any issues.

```
    public XmlDocument formatMeeting()
    {
        //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb894186(v=office.12).aspx
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        string requestString = null;
        ////requestString+="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";
        //requestString += "<PlaceWareConfCenter authUser=\"icey.x.shen@gsk.com\" authPassword=\"gsk123456\">";
        //requestString += "<CreateMeetingRequest maxUsers=\"100\" name=\"ShipParty\" title=\"Come to celebrate\">";
        //requestString += "<OptionList>";
        //requestString += "<TimeOption name=\"startTime\" value=\"2015-10-27T14:00:00Z\"/>";
        //requestString += "<TimeOption name=\"endTime\" value=\"2015-10-27T18:00:00Z\"/>";
        ////requestString += "<StringOption name=\"timeZone\" value=\"America/Los_Angeles\"/>";
        ////requestString += "<EnumerationOption name=\"meetingType\" value=\"OneTime\">";
        //// requestString += "<String>OneTime</String>";
        ////requestString += "<String>MeetNow</String>";
        //// requestString += "<String>Recurring</String>";
        //// requestString += "</EnumerationOption>";
        //requestString += "</OptionList>";
        //requestString += "<FieldList>";
        //requestString += "<Name>mid</Name>";
        //requestString += "<Name>name</Name>";
        ////requestString += "<Name>meetingType</Name>";
        //requestString += "<Name>presenterPassword</Name>";
        //requestString += "<Name>audiencePassword</Name>";
        //requestString += "</FieldList>";
        //requestString += "</CreateMeetingRequest>";
        //requestString += "</PlaceWareConfCenter>";

        //requestString += "<PlaceWareConfCenter authUser=\"icey.x.shen@gsk.com\" authPassword=\"gsk123456\">";
        //requestString+="<ListMeetingsRequest listDeleted=\"True\">";
        //requestString+="<TimeIntervalQuery fieldName=\"startTime\">";
        //requestString+="<TimeInterval startTime=\"2015-07-27T00:00:00Z\"";
        //requestString+=" endTime=\"2015-10-11T22:00:00Z\"/>";
        //requestString+="</TimeIntervalQuery>";
        //requestString+="<FieldList>";
        //requestString+="<Name>name</Name>";
        //requestString+="<Name>mid</Name>";
        //requestString+="<Name>owner</Name>";
        //requestString+="<Name>title</Name>";
        //requestString+="<Name>presenterList</Name>";
        //requestString+="<Name>startTime</Name>";
        //requestString+="<Name>endTime</Name>";
        //requestString+="<Name>location</Name>";
        //requestString+="<Name>removeTime</Name>";
        //requestString+="</FieldList>";
        //requestString+="</ListMeetingsRequest>";
        //requestString+="</PlaceWareConfCenter>";

        //requestString += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";
        requestString += "<PlaceWareConfCenter authUser=\"icey.x.shen@gsk.com\" authPassword=\"gsk123456\">";
        requestString += "<ListMeetingsRequest listDeleted=\"False\">";
        requestString += "<StringQuery fieldName=\"mid\" operator=\"=\" value=\"F8TZSD\"/>";
        requestString += "<FieldList>";
        requestString += "<Name>name</Name>";
        requestString += "</FieldList>";
        requestString += "</ListMeetingsRequest>";
        requestString += "</PlaceWareConfCenter>";
        //requestString.AppendFormat("<PlaceWareConfCenter authUser=\"icey.x.shen@gsk.com \" authPassword=\"gsk123456\">");
        //requestString.AppendFormat("<ListMeetingsRequest listDeleted=\"False\">");
        //requestString.AppendFormat("<StringQuery fieldName=\"mid\" operator=\"=\" value=\"J8H64N\"/>");
        //requestString.AppendFormat("<FieldList>");
        //requestString.AppendFormat("<Name>name</Name>");
        //requestString.AppendFormat("</FieldList>");
        //requestString.AppendFormat("</ListMeetingsRequest>");
        //requestString.AppendFormat("</PlaceWareConfCenter>");
        xmldoc.LoadXml(requestString);
        return xmldoc;
    }
```

Everything I tried. Let me know if you can see any discrepancies.

-Sam

Comment: Please validate  (and possibly format) XML you've shown in the post and consider also showing code you use to send request and specify service you are trying to call.

Comment: Added code and more info. I am on this issue for 4 days. Really appreciate some help!

Comment: You should create your XML in another way. LINQ to XML for ex.

Comment: Not to say that I have tried different way and text. This was just to show that what are the things I have tried.

Comment: Issue is now resolved. Not sure what was going wrong. I used fiddler and checked. I was actually getting Authentication ERROR but my VS Error Window kept displaying Parse Error. Once I got the Ticket and send it with the request instead of UserId and Password. It worked fine.